# Show sublist value from index C#

Tags: c#, list, indexof

My problem is I have M subproblem. Each subproblem include x (double array) and reduced cost which has different value for each iteration m. I want to show x which has the minimum reduced cost among all subproblems. here is my class:

```
public class Subproblem
{
    public double[,] x { get; set; }
    public double ReducedCost { get; set; }
}
```

So far, I already can get the minimum Reduced Cost and index of it. Now I want to show x value (double array) which on that index. I've code like this:

```
var sub = new List<Subproblem>();
for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m)
{
Subproblem s = new Subproblem();
s.x = new double[DC1, DC1];      
s.ReducedCost = model.ObjVal;
    for (int i = 0; i < DC1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DC1; ++j)
        {
            s.x[i, j] = x[i, j].X;
        }
    }
    sub.Add(s);
}
double minRC = sub.Min(a => a.ReducedCost);
int minRCIndex = sub.FindIndex((i) => i.ReducedCost == minRC);
Console.WriteLine(sub.x(minRCIndex));
```

the last line (`Console.WriteLine(sub.x(minRCIndex));`) still got red underline, I don't know how to write it

Comment: Console.WriteLine(sub.x[minRCIndex]);

Comment: @rraszewski, `sub` is a `List` and doesn't contain `x`.

Comment: Your `sub` is just the list referenced to same object for m times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
var objWithMinReduceCost = sub[minRCIndex];
//Now you have the object of Subproblem derived from your logic.
//You can access x property of it have further logic to process it.
for (int i = 0; i < DC1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < DC1; ++j)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(objWithMinReduceCost.x[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: since the `sub.x` is a doubly array, the element at `minRCIndex` will again be an array. Hence this statement wouldn't give a value. Would it?

Comment: It is not clear that what could be value of DC1. So not sure of what should be the value passed as next index in final sub.x []. So just to guide author  about how it can be accessed I put 0 as second index. Also the answer by rraszewski is now different from mine.

Comment: `sub` is a `List` and doesn't contain `x`, so this won't even compile.

Comment: Got it... completely missed it.. I corrected my answer now.

Comment: @ArlitaNurmayaAsri, I still recommend you use the method in my answer. Instead of getting the index and then accessing that index, why don't you just get the element at once? Use `First` and your code will be a little less convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only trying to get the minimum Reduced Costed subproblem you should be doing:

```
Subproblem minimumReducedCostedSubproblem = sub[minRCIndex];
```

And you can print the matrix down like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DC1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < DC1; ++j)
    {
        Console.Write(minimumReducedCostedSubproblem.x[i, j] + "\t");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

But you seem a little confused. You are pushing a Subproblem into your `sub` list with the same object for `M` times. Because `model.ObjVal` doesn't change along the first `for` loop. There is something wierd going on there too.

Comment: My problem is I have M subproblem. Each subproblem is a list which include x (double array) and reduced cost which has different value for each iteration m. I want to show x which has the minimum reduced cost among all subproblem. So far I already can find the minimum reduced cost and index of it. Now I want to show x which on that index

Comment: how are you planning to show the `x`? The `x` is a matrix, you need a custom writer for it in order to console write it. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes actually like that, but for now I just want to show the value. Chetan already know what I want

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in obtaining the `double` array, you could just do this:

```
double[,] result = sub.First(i => i.ReducedCost == minRC).x;
```

Although as Tolga mentioned, all your elements will have the same `ReducedCost` with your current code.